# Default destructor blocked on a mutex

Tags: c++

I got code like below for an experiment:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() : mThread(&Foo::test, this) {

  }
 private:
  std::thread mThread;
  std::mutex mMutex;
  std::condition_variable mCv;
  void test() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
    mCv.wait(lock);
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  usleep(1000);
  std::cout << "wake up" << std::endl;
}
```

And the code will block at the destructor of `Foo`, after debugging, I found out that the thread  is blocked on `futex_wait`, but double check the document of `wait()` of `condition_variable`, it says that

> At the moment of blocking the thread, the function automatically calls
>   lck.unlock(), allowing other locked threads to continue.

So why my code still blocked at mMutex since `mCv` has `unlocked`?

P.S. I know this design pattern has problems, I just curious if I'm missing some knowledge about  thread conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior. At the closing brace of `main`, `foo` is destroyed, and so are its member variables, beginning with `mCv`. The standard says:

> **[thread.condition.condvar]/5**
>
> ```
> ~condition_variable();
> ```
>
> *Requires*: There shall be no thread blocked on `*this`. [ Note: That is, all threads shall have been notified... —end note ]

Your program violates the *Requires* clause, as `test` in another thread waits on `mCv` and has not been notified.